# I want to override style of div of MenuItem component in material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I somehow able to overide css of menuitem by doing this.

```
const styles = () => ({
  root: {
    top:65
  },
});

const Picker = ({
  classes, identifier, topLabel, onSelection, options, selectedValue,
}) => (
  <form  autoComplete="off">
    <TextField
      name={identifier}
      select
      label={topLabel}
      value={selectedValue}
      onChange={onSelection}
    >
      {options.map(({ label, value }) => (
        <MenuItem className={classes.root} key={value} value={value}>{label}</MenuItem>
      ))}
    </TextField>
  </form>
);
```

but now the concern is this the snapshot of generated output is below -
[image]

First ul item is at 60 px from top, but what I want is to put this entire div 60 px down from the element that is above it so that it should not hide element below it.

but when I inspect it and do it manually to the div element of menuitem it works what it is doing is applying my modified properties to the ul element instead of the parent div.
see screenshot below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think just need to do like this, add more div and make it margin-top

```
const styles = () => ({
  root: {
    top:65
  },
});

const Picker = ({
  classes, identifier, topLabel, onSelection, options, selectedValue,
}) => (
  <form  autoComplete="off">
    <TextField
      name={identifier}
      select
      label={topLabel}
      value={selectedValue}
      onChange={onSelection}
    >
      <div className={classes.root}>
        {options.map(({ label, value }) => (
          <MenuItem key={value} value={value}>{label}</MenuItem>
        ))}
      </div>
    </TextField>
  </form>
);
```

Comment: and where to define css rules for custom-menu-item?

Comment: just see your attacted code now. let me add more in answer

Comment: I think that will use an other solution. make TextField have a custom className and use that class to find first div child for CSS

Comment: but here I want to find first child of menuitem that is a div having childrens as ul list.

Comment: @Tony Doung let me give it a try. i have also updated Question and added an screenshot.

Comment: one more thing the application I am working on does not have a seperate stylesheet, all the styles are defined as follows,  const styles = () => ({
  root: {
    top:65
  },
}); so how to achieve first child behavious here, as mentioned by you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181010/discussion-between-divyanshu-rawat-and-tung-duong).